# Weighted correlation with uncertainty on both groups

Tags: correlation, meta-analysis

I want to estimate the correlation between two studies, which studied the same variables in two different conditions. For each variable I have an estimate (b), standard error (se) and p-value (p). Sample size between the two studies differ substantially, so my first thought was to scale the estimates by their corresponding standard error in each study and measure the correlation between the scaled estimates.

$$
z_{ij} = \frac{b_{ij}}{se_{ij}}
$$

As an example, I measure the correlation between variables in study 1 and 2 like this:

$$
r = \frac{\sum (z_{i1} - \bar{z_{i1}})(z_{i2} - \bar{z_{i2}})}{\sum (z_{i1} - \bar{z_{i1}})^{2} \sum (z_{i2} - \bar{z_{i2}})^{2}}
$$

where $b_{ij}$ is the $i^{th}$ estimate of the $j^{th}$ study. I then measure the correlation of $z_{ij}$, so that high estimates with low sample size will be shrunk towards zero.

I have also tried weighted correlation, but most formulas I could find only allow for a single vector of weights. I would to provide the formula two vectors of weights, one for each group, to take uncertainty in both groups into account.

Is there any problems with the above approach? If so, what are the issues of doing this, and what are other methods to take uncertainty into account in both groups?